# Table cell alignment is driving me crazy

Tags: html, css, padding, css-tables

I am not sure what CSS I need to apply to make all of these tables the same exact height/padding.

See how Step and Abs aren't align with the others (look at the bottom border) - that is driving me insane, I have no idea how to just get it straight.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://www.thedynamicfitness.com/pearland/classes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add `vertical-align: top;` to your `td` all contents is properly aligned with the white border (until all titles are 1-row wide)